# Route not found even though It's defined

Tags: laravel, routes

This is the error that I get rolled out
(View: Route [user.profile] not defined. (View: D:\Programi\XAMPP\htdocs\crushapp\resources\views\layouts\base.blade.php)

But my route is clearly defined here:

```
use App\Http\Livewire\User\ProfileComponent;
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','verified'])->group(function()
{
    Route::get('/user/profile',ProfileComponent::class)->name('user.profile');
    
});
```

The error comes from the layout, namely:

```
<span><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="{{ route('user.profile') }}">{{ Auth::user()->name }}  ‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‎‏‏</a></span>
```

Any ideas what could it be?

UPDATE: Any new route I try defining under user won't work...

Comment: Where is your function name in controller in route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you are missing a function name in your route
also run `php artisan route:clear`

```
Route::get('/user/profile',ProfileComponent::class, 'index')->name('user.profile')
```

Comment: This helped me solve it, but I don't understand how it's relevant when I'm running it out of a component and  not Controller? I don't have a "index" function defined in my component and I've defined many other components without it and they've worked. 

Thank you anyways!

Comment: @Praise what if I use different route uri for example Route::get('profile', ProfileComponent::class, 'index')->name('user.profile'); but have route name user.profile, how can I make it defined? Thank you